# Retrieve html tags with multiple class names using xpath

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am using HTMLAgility pack for extracting the contents of some html pages and i use the below code of html

```
span class="custombutton selling_price"
```

So how can i access the contents in span with 2 class names
The xpath i used is here

```
//span[@class='custombutton selling_price']
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally recommend using this construction to search for space-delimited attribute values:

```
contains(concat(' ', @attr, ' '), concat(' ', $value, ' '))
```

This attaches a space to both ends of the values, making sure you don't get partial matches.

Since CSS classes do not have a specific order, searching for two of them means doing the above two times:

```
//span[
    contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' custombutton ') and
    contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' selling_price ')
]
```